# How to Save do an callback/action when all divs are rendered using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I am iterating through list of divs,converting them to canvas and then adding them to jspdf.

After doing all these I am saving them to disk.

```
   function exportDataTablesAsPDF() {
        var dataTablesToBeExported = $('.js-exportdiv');


        $.each(dataTablesToBeExported, function (index, element) {

            html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                masterPdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            });
        });
       masterPdf.save("Test.pdf");
    }
```

But the problem here is , masterPdf.save() executes before all canvas call backs are complete.

The pdf gets downloaded befoe all the images are added to the document. Is there a way, I can wait for all `then(canvas)` to finish and download the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try calling `masterPdf.save` after all the images have been added.

Something like

```
 function exportDataTablesAsPDF() {
        var dataTablesToBeExported = $('.js-exportdiv');
        var numberOfImages = dataTablesToBeExported.length;


        $.each(dataTablesToBeExported, function (index, element) {

            html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                masterPdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                if (index + 1 == numberOfImages) { masterPdf.save("Test.pdf"); }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think you are doing the same thing as written in the question because the JS function is synchronous and save method is calling only after whole $.each finished.

Comment: I believe that `html2canvas` is the async code here and `masterPdf.addImage` is sync. Obviously, it is hard to be sure about that without knowing what class `masterPdf` belongs to @UllasHunka.